# Apache server as proxy to Jboss problem

Tags: java, apache, http, jboss, http-headers

Currently my web application is running on jboss but I have an apache server that is used as a proxy to my application. I have the ability to upload XML files on my jboss server. When it is uploaded, it returns HTTP 200 and XML response `Content-Type: text/xml`.

Some users use this feature on apache instance that redirects to jboss. These users sometimes use Content-Type: application/xml when they upload file and Accept: / header. With this header jboss does the work OK, but apache always returns bad response:

```
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
< Date: Mon, 31 Jan 2011 23:33:47 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) mod_jk/1.2.27
< Content-Length: 232
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Gateway</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
</p>
```

Why does it happen when users use application/xml instead of text/xml header value? Does apache compare these headers in some way? When users use text/xml value everything is ok and apache prints jboss 200 OK response.

Comment: Which method are you using to route messages from httpd-to->jboss? mod_jk, mod_proxy or other? This response Header that you paste here, how it was originated? Do you have a request packet to paste here?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using apache2 .
edit this file
/etc/apache2/modsenabled/mime.conf
add one line
AddType application/xml .xml

--kiran.kumar

Answer (score 0):

You may need to examine mime.types file in the httpd/conf directory (usually somewhere like the /usr/httpd/conf or /etc/httpd/conf directory) and set file extensions for application/xml the same as set for text/xml .